# Find out the duplicate values in the List

Tags: c#, list

I tried to find out the duplicate value in a list.

However, my list's type is not primitive types, and I want to know which elements in the list are duplicate one.

For example, I have three "**Person**" classes in `List<Person>`, **people**, like the following codes.

My filter is "**Gender**" property of Person class, and the targeted result should contain "Mary" and "Sandy" objects since their Gender's values are the same-->female.

```
Person Paul = new Person() { Name="Paul", Gender="male", Age="15"};
Person Mary = new Person() { Name = "Mary", Gender = "female", Age = "22" };
Person Sandy = new Person() { Name = "Sandy", Gender = "female", Age = "13" };

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(Paul);
people.Add(Mary);
people.Add(Sandy);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, don't indent your plain text. Indent your _code_ by four spaces, not your text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to find the "duplicates", then restrict by count:

```
var duplicates = people.GroupBy(p => p.Gender)
                       .Where (g => g.Count() >= 2);
```

At which point you can just enumerate:

```
foreach (Person person in duplicates)
{
   Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want *grouping*, not finding duplicates. You can do this using the LINQ `GroupBy` method:

```
people.GroupBy(p => p.Gender)
```

This will return an `IGrouping<string, Person>`, `string` being the group *key* type.

A similar method is to use a *lookup*:

```
var peopleByGender = people.ToLookup(p => p.Gender);
var females = peopleByGender["female"]; // An IEnumerable<Person> containing Mary and Sandy
```

This returns an `ILookup<string, Person>`, which is just like a dictionary, except the same key can be present multiple times.

On a side note, you should probably use an enum for the gender.

Comment: And then test the count to see if the key has a unique pair in the original list. That's what you are thinking right?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama yes, I should have stated that but it was still a bit unclear for me what exactly the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
people.Where(p => p.Gender.Equals("female").ToList();
```

Should give you what you want

Comment: This only handles one case. If he doesn't know what the case is he can't identify distinctness or not.

Comment: @Admiral : But in case of complex object you should know key(s) on which you filter data.

Comment: @PankajKapare The bigger problem is that this doesn't detect if there is more than one female or not. The condition was based on "female" occurring more than once, not just the string.

Comment: Eh I disagree with that sentiment. What if your users are adding their location to their profile and you just want to know if you are underpenetrated into some location by looking for unique cities. I know what you are saying, but it can't fit all situations, least of all individuals.